# Logging in spring boot

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot

I have tried different ways to configure logging in spring boot and took the help of different blogs but nothing seems to be working for me. I have specified log4j.properties in src/main/reosurces folder and executing the application, It creates the logs for me. BUT when I use external log4j.properties and provide below property while executing my application by jar

```
-Dlogging.config=/path/to/log4j.properties
```

The log file is not getting generated. Below is snippet of my build.gradle file.

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group:  'com.sun.jdmk', module: 'jmxtools'
    exclude group:  'com.sun.jmx', module: 'jmxri'
    exclude group:  'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
}
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Spring Boot by default uses logback. So providing a `log4j.properties` isn't really going to help. You can specify log level simply in the `application.properties`. What is so special you need your own properties fie?

Comment: @M.Deinum  I want external logging configuration. I have also tried logging.file and logging.path in application.properties. It is not working. I don't understand what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the spring-boot logging documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

If you want to use log4j in combination with spring-boot, you need to exclude the default logging dependencies and add log4j as your logging framework.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The OP is using gradle, so you should probably use that as an example rather than maven.